# Is a laptop batery some kind of uninterrupted power supply for a laptop system

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, power-supply, battery

I preferred using my laptop on AC{Battery Unplugged} because the System suggested that performance is better while on AC{unplugged battery} than when on DC, So i decided to remove the battery and use it in AC mode and it was remarkably fast in this mode when compared to when on DC{Battery} until this happened.Sudden Power Outages,an outage caused errors on the hard drive which made the laptop show this message on boot {Fixing hard drive Errors}, But checking on my laptop history usage with battery, this error has never occurred. So there is a dilemma here, either use the laptop in AC mode but prepare to fix errors caused by sudden power outages or use it with battery and completely use a slow laptop in balanced performance mode. So is the laptop battery some kind of UPS{Uninterrupted Power Supply} that protects the system hard drive from damages caused by sudden power outages when in AC mode? When i use it on battery, i noticed that windows is very intelligent to know that its shutting down and save a copy of the session on the hard drive, then next time when i turn it on after recharging it, it resumes the session with the exact same programs i had open before.
So why does Windows fail to detect shutdown on sudden power outage but can do it in battery mode and even save a copy of the session in hard drive?

`I asked this because real desktop systems are connected to a UPS which behaves the same way as a laptop battery, it protects the hard drive from damage caused by sudden power outage}`

Comment: _"So why does Windows fail to detect shutdown on sudden power outage but can do it in battery mode and even save a copy of the session in hard drive?"_ - I'm not sure if I understand your question. Are you asking why a computer immediately stops working when it has no power source?

Comment: Am asking why battery never causes hard drive errors when its fully discharging while AC damages the hard drive when sudden outage occurs?

Comment: It knows when the battery is about to go flat & will shut down or hibernate accordingly. It has zero chance to react to the mains power suddenly going off.

Comment: So when in AC i need a UPS like that of PC?

Comment: Why not just reconnect the battery, that's what it's for. Laptops are not designed to run on mains only. The charger is for charging the battery, the battery is for powering the laptop.

Comment: But performance in battery mode is slow, even when plugged in?I beg to differ, the charger is for both because it still powers on laptop even when battery is not in

Comment: If it's slower when plugged in then you have a setting wrong somewhere, or the battery is already dying. Plus - a UPS is more expensive than a battery, & incidentally also itself contains a much more expensive battery which will need replacing periodically. The laptop battery itself will fare a lot better if charged & discharged in normal usage than it will if disconnected for long periods - that will kill it much faster than using it.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your help, i really appreciate it

Comment: My laptop performs slightly worse *while charging* the battery because the process of charging a battery draws power and generates heat. Once at 100% charge I have full performance. While you shouldn't really leave it on charge all day every day it should not appreciably damage the battery or laptop.

Comment: Okay and Thanks for the tip :))

Comment: "performance in battery mode is slow, even when plugged in"  There is something wrong with your computer (driver, BIOS updates needed perhaps). The charging circuit could have a problem.  I never had a laptop plugged in to AC that slowed down because of a battery in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct: the laptop battery acts as an "uninterruptible power supply" (UPS) to your computer.

A Windows (or any other operating system) computer without battery power simply cannot detect a sudden power loss, because the operating system is just a piece of software running on a CPU, *which does need power to function*. With a battery, and working battery management (measuring the power consumption over time, and estimating the remaining charge), it is possible to *gracefully* shut down when the battery charge drops below a certain point (e.g. 15%).

On battery-only operation, systems can be configured (or are configured by default) to be less-performant. This is mostly done in order to prolong the time until battery depletion, and thus to increase the usable time. But the system performance "with battery and AC" should be the same as "with AC only"... at least after the battery has been fully charged.

I'd recommend *not* to work with the battery disconnected. Please do not expect always to be able to "fix" errors after a sudden power loss. If the system is (mostly) idle, "fixing" appears to work most of the time... but if a crash happens when the system is under heavy load (e.g. compiling or - even worse! - is trying to "fix" corrupt data), the result of an incomplete interrupted write can be very damaging to the integrity of your data.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I don't think you've answered the question that was asked. Fair enough, because it wasn't articulated clearly - see my question in the comments and OP's response.

Comment: @gronostaj you are right, was difficult to detect "the" question :)

Answer (score -1):

Of course your battery protects your hardware from getting fried. When you draw power from a DC battery the power is constant.  That's why most power generators such as solar or water uses a battery as medium to provide constant stable energy.

Windows does all of those functions base off the battery state on the laptop, it got nothing to do with a surge from the AC source.  You are referring to feature that get triggered in different situations from what you experienced.

I mean if the battery somehow get sort of short on the output as well then that won't help protecting your laptop.  But in most of cases you will be alright or do away with a battery replacement.

Comment: Sorry, but I have some basic knowledge of how a laptop's charging circuit works and I don't understand what you're trying to say. I don't think a beginner will get it. What does it mean that _"When you draw power from a DC battery the power is constant"_? The voltage is (more or less) constant, but the power draw definitely isn't.

Comment: Power draw is not power and a beginner will definitely not know what a power draw is if they don't know what power is.  please be constructive and explain what a voltage is instead of wrongfully correcting terms.